# Which DB technology is sued to solve the following search issue?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Assume I have built a video sharing site such as youtube, and I want to build a recommendation system.

Assume I have a simple database [ video title, link/url to database ]

Lets assume user watches a video simply tiled - 'Sachin Tendulkar'.
How can I run a query to return me other videos whose search title `includes` sachin tendulkar ?

eg: other videos could be titled -

`Straight drive by Sachin Tendulkar` or `Sachin Tendulkars famous reply to Bret Lee`.

In other words, which query can I run to fetch all the videos whose title contains Sachin ?

Comment: No code, no research, no effort - not the place for this type of question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Practically any database should be able to run such queries.

In the case of SQL, using a simple `WHERE ... LIKE ...` condition with wildcards should be sufficient for simple cases.

The interesting question will be how to scale this once you are dealing with much larger amounts of data, think YouTube for video portals. But until performance really becomes an issue, adding additional complexity can most likely be considered premature optimization and should be avoided.